# Using $scope inside ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

using the following code I can't get my parent scope nor the $scope to bind.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
...
   <div ng-include="sidebarbar.url"></div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataProvider', 'SidebarService', function ($scope, DataProvider, SidebarService) {
//Initialize
$scope.data= DataProvider;
...
```

in my index.html inside the controller I have full access to my data scope now I need to display parts of this data inside a sidebar view, SiderbarServices opens the sidebar, sets the slected ID which all works

details.html (which is the one opened by ng-include)

```
<div ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('test'); //is displayed
    console.log(data); //not defined
    console.log($parent); //not defined
    console.log(testScope); //not defined
    </script>
</div>
```

details.js (controller)

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data= $scope.$parent.data;
    $scope.testScope = 'testing if available';

    console.log($scope); //is displayed
    console.log($scope.data); //is displayed
}]);
```

How can I get access to the data from inside ng-include? (I can't use views as I'm already routing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for details.html:

```
<div ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('test'); //is displayed
    console.log(data); //not defined
    console.log($parent); //not defined
    console.log(testScope); //not defined
    </script> -->
    <div>{{data}}</div>
</div>
```

and replace this code in main html:

```
<div ng-include="'details.html'"></div>
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WOTFWPjywjIrXpAFBEQk?p=preview) it is working

you have done this mistake : it should be `ng-include="'details.html'"`  not `ng-include="details.html"`

and `<script>` tag do not work inside `ng-controller`.

Comment: I tried in my code and still does not work, ng-include is changed from an object. This part works the page opens and static content is displayed. 

I did now get it to work by using `$parent.data.key`

 Thanks for the help